# comparing date not Working in php

Tags: php

I have two dates here and want to compare with another date ...
   another date here is called $date_main and compared it with a variable called $date_to ... Help it's not working..

```
<?php
        $date_f="02-05-2014"; 
        $date_t="02-11-2014"; 

        $date_from=date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date_f));
        $date_to=date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date_t));

        $date_c="21-7-2014";

        $date_main=date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date_c));

        if(($date_main<$date_to))
        {
            echo "date_main is less then to<br/>";
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: U need to use the DateTime class for this

Comment: Or just use strtotime and compare the timestamp values.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to compare the times and not the dates itself:

```
if(strtotime($date_c) < strtotime($date_t))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering why not doing something like this?

```
$date_f = "02-05-2014";
$date_t = "02-11-2014";

$date_from = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $date_f);
$date_to = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $date_t);
$date_main=DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '21-07-2014');

if (($date_main < $date_to)) {
    echo "date_main is less then to<br/>";
}
```

Working with objects is always better.

Comment: Error: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Comment: Fixed, I forgot to convert to DateTime! :)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     $date_f="02-05-2014"; 
>     $date_t="02-11-2014";    
>     $date_main=date_create("2014-7-21");      
>     $date_to=date_create("2014-11-02");       
>     $diff=date_diff($date_main,$date_to);
>     if($diff->format("%R%a")>0)       
>       {
>         echo "date_to is greater";      
>       }         
>       else      
>       {         
>          echo "date_main is greater";   
>       }
> ```